# O que é scoped em C#?

Tags: c#, parâmetros

Enquanto analisava alguns códigos fontes do motor do .NET, eu achei [este trecho de código](https://source.dot.net/System.Private.CoreLib/A.html#42cc3737aaf82c63):

```
public static ref T AsRef<T>(scoped in T source)
{
    throw new PlatformNotSupportedException();

    //ldarg .0
    //ret
}
```

E apareceu uma palavra que nunca havia visto antes na linguagem: `scoped`.

O que ela faz? Para o que serve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É um recurso mais avançando e mais difícil de entender (eu ainda não peguei totalmente). Assim como é difícil em Rust. A comparação faz sentido porque C# introduziu uma forma limitada de controle de tempo de vida, algo que Rust tem muito mais sofisticado, e difícil.

Antes C# conseguia controlar o tempo de vida muito bem, até melhor que Rust, por conta própria. Mas em certas situações Rust permite explicitamente declarar qual é o tempo de vida, C# não, então nesses casos a solução do C# sempre foi mito mais simples, joga no *heap* e o *runtime* (GC) cuida do tempo de vida. Só que isso é ineficiente.

Se você quer manter o objeto na *stack*, e só assim o comando é necessário, em alguns casos, quando tenta capturar objetos com certo tempo de vida que o compilador não consegue determinar que não dará problema, você tem que informar isso, colocando o `scoped`.

Note também que é necessário que a passagem do parâmetro seja feita por referência, sem referência nunca dá problema.

Classes são assim, mas elas estão sempre no *heap*, então só vale para `ref struct` ou equivalente, que estão sempre na *stack*.

O [`scoped`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/low-level-struct-improvements#scoped-modifier) cria uma limitação porque você não pode mais retornar o objeto pelo método (`AsRef()` no exemplo da pergunta). O normal é deixar fazer isso, mas o uso do `scoped` faz o compilador não permitir mais. Assim protege de um resultado potencialmente inadequado aumentando o tempo dew vida indevidamente. O uso dele promete que você não fará isso.

Eu ainda não faço ideia como usar com *generics*, mas um exemplo:

```
using System;

Span<int> x = stackalloc int[1];
Test obj = new();
obj.Method(x);

public ref struct Test {
    public void Method(scoped Span<int> values) {}
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/u1cbdA). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/Scoped1.cs).

Veja o erro:

```
using System;

Span<int> x = stackalloc int[1];
Test obj = new();
obj.Method(x);

public ref struct Test {
    public void Method(Span<int> values) {}
}
```

Veja [**não** funcionando no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QgsgCH). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/Scoped2.cs).

> Compilation error (line 5, col 12): Cannot use variable 'x' in this context because it may expose referenced variables outside of their declaration scope
>
> Compilation error (line 5, col 1): This combination of arguments to 'Test.Method(Span)' is disallowed because it may expose variables referenced by parameter 'values' outside of their declaration scope

Tentando retornar o objeto:

```
using System;

Span<int> x = stackalloc int[1];
Test obj = new();
obj.Method(x);

public ref struct Test {
    public Span<int> Method(scoped Span<int> values) => values;
}
```

Veja [**não** funcionando no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/W7z0oX). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/Scoped3.cs).

> Compilation error (line 8, col 57): Cannot use variable 'Span' in this context because it may expose referenced variables outside of their declaration scope

Então você está garantindo o uso em um cenário que antes não era possível sem comprometer o uso de uma referência que poderia superar o tempo de vida real do objeto.

Java não permite ter nada disso. C# antigo não permitia esse cenário, só outros. Rust permite mais cenários, mas é mais difícil de usar. C++ permite qualquer cenário, mas pode corromper a memória.

Lembrando que isso é usado apenas por otimização.

[Documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-11.0/low-level-struct-improvements?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).